# How to detect a hostednetwork is launched?

Tags: c#, command-line, windows-10, netsh, access-point

I have a program launching a hotspot using c# with command line `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`. However I have no idea the hosted network is successfully launched or not.

Using commands like `netsh wlan show hostednetwork` cannot solve the problem because it depends on the system language. I cannot determine the output programmatically.

How can I know the hotspot has been successfully launched or say the command line is executed successfully?

```
public void Launch ()
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo ("cmd.exe", "/c netsh wlan start hostednetwork");
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    Process.Start (processStartInfo);
}
```

Comment: " I cannot determine the output programmatically"...off the top of my head I don't know what this program returns, if anything, but I do know that C# can capture the output of a console program.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, you can capture the output but you cannot know the launching status by determining the output.

Comment: "you cannot know the launching status by determining the output" surely that depends on what the program outputs? Are you saying this one doesn't output anything useful? How, manually, do you determine whether the hotspot is live or not? There _should_ be some kind of automatic way to detect it. Might also be worth checking if there's a powershell equivalent of the command as that would be likely to write more properly to stdErr for instance if anything went wrong.

Comment: "How, manually, do you determine whether the hotspot is live or not?", type the command line "netsh wlan show hostednetwork" and look at its cmd output, if the column "狀態" is "已啟動", it means the hotspot is launched.

Comment: So then, if that's included in the cmd output, you can read this in C#, no? And if it's not there, then the hotspot is not live

Comment: No, I cannot determine the status by "reading" the output because of the system language. The keywords varies from the language. If I am using English for my system language, the column "狀態" may become "Status" and "已啟動" become "Started".

Comment: Yes Ok I get that, but my point was, can you compare it to how the output is structured (as opposed to what it actually says) when the hotspot is _not_ live? Is there some difference in presentation (e.g. absence of info, or maybe it writes to stdErr instead of stdOut or something), as opposed to merely a difference in words? Maybe there isn't, but I'm just trying to think through possibilities for you to try.

Comment: what about differing return values (as opposed to cmd output)?

Comment: Too risky to compare number of output lines I'm afraid.